# Why am I getting a code 2 : "No matching files"?

Tags: gitignore, prettier

Could someone explain to me why I have this result ?
I try to run : `npx prettier --c .`

.prettierignore :

```
*
!src/app/
!src/app/**
```

The result :

```
[error] No matching files. Patterns tried: . !**/node_modules/** !./node_modules/** !**/.{git,svn,hg}/** !./.{git,svn,hg}/**
All matched files use Prettier code style!
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path D:\Users\Guillaume\Documents\Work\project-front
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "prettier "--check" ".""
```

Comment: I tried with the folder names instead of the * but no result.

Answer (score 1):

That's how the [`gitignore` syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) works. Scroll to the end of that page and you'll see an example very similar to yours.

Apparently, here's what your `.prettierignore` should look like:

```
/*
!/src
/src/*
!/src/app
```